# HTML5 Drag & Drop : "dragleave" isn't called when "dragover" and "drop" events are listened

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, dom-events, draggable, drag

I have div included in another parent div that are both allowed for "drop".
Two cases:

Case 1 : Drop event is not allowed:
When I drop element in child box both execute dragleave event so red class is removed for both elements correctly but `drop` is not executed

Case 2: Drop event is allowed (by removing comment in js code): 
When I drop element in child box, dragleave event is not executed and I remove red class only on child element (code included in "drop" event listener)

**Questions :** 
In case 2, If I drop the element into the `div` named child, the red class is only removed in child `div` and not in parent `div`. What to do for removing class in all parents without going through `event.path` object?

Here is the [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19492/) for case 1
Here is the [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19494/) for case 2

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope)
            {
            }]);


myApp.directive('drop', function() {
return{
  restrict: "A",
    replace: false,

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctlr) {
     var obj = element[0];
  var DragLeaveCounter=0;
        
        obj.addEventListener("dragenter", function (eventObject) {
            eventObject.preventDefault();
            DragLeaveCounter++;
            if (DragLeaveCounter === 1) {
                    obj.classList.add( 'red' );
                };
           console.log("enter" , obj.id , DragLeaveCounter );
        }, false);

        obj.addEventListener("dragleave", function (eventObject) {
            eventObject.preventDefault();
            DragLeaveCounter--;
           if (DragLeaveCounter <= 0) {
                obj.classList.remove('red');
           }
            console.log("leave" , obj.id , DragLeaveCounter);
        }, false);


        obj.addEventListener("drop", function (eventObject) {
            eventObject.preventDefault();
            eventObject.stopPropagation();
            console.log("drop" , obj.id , eventObject);           
            obj.classList.remove("red");
            DragLeaveCounter=0;

        }, false);


        obj.addEventListener("dragover", function (eventObject) {
           //TODO Remove comment in next line: 
           eventObject.preventDefault();
            console.log("dragover");
        }, false);

        
    }
    
}
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

#parent{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}

#child{
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:50px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#c7a499;
}
#child2{
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:110px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#c7a499;
}

.red {
    background-color: red !important;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
    <i> Remove comment on line 43 in js to see what the difference (Please open the console)</i>
    <div id="drag"  draggable="true">drag me</div>
    <hr>

    <div id="parent" drop>
        Parent
        <div id="child" drop> 
            child
        </div>
        <div id="child2" > 
            child 2
        </div>
        
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems that the problem comes from that `eventObject.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

When the `drop` event is fired the correct behaviour of the drag&drop functionality is to not fire a `dragleave` event. If you don't use the `event.preventDefault()` on the `drop` event then the browser tries to execute that drop action (IE: to load a link when you drop it in the browser). This cause that the `leave` events get triggered.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#drop

You should leave the `drop` event to propagate upwards to gather the event in the parent removing that `eventObject.stopPropagation();` in the drop listener.

Comment: Yes, but if I remove stopPropagation, that's right that it will remove the class but it will also execute the drop operation to all elements.

Comment: I have rewrite the question in another way here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516226/html5-drag-drop-how-to-remove-class-added-in-dragenter-in-all-parent-when-dr