# HTML5 Drag & Drop : How to remove class added in dragenter in all parent when drop event executed (so dragleave is not executed for removing it)

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, dom-events, draggable, drag

I Have `div` included in another parent `div` that are both allowed for "drop".

In the example a class named "red" is added to all droppable object in `dragenter` event. So if I enter the mouse durring drag in child element **both child and parent will get "red" class.**

When I abort the drag&drop or if I leave elements during operation, the `dragleave` event will remove the added "red" class.

The problem is when I drop the element into child there are two options :

Option 1 : `event.stopPropagation()` **is included** in `drop` event
The problem is that in this case, the parent won't execute the `drop` event and the "red" class will not be removed at all in parent.

Option 2: `event.stopPropagation()` **is not included** in `drop` event
The problem is that in this case the `drop` event will be executed for both child and parent element. But the drop action should be done only for child element.

I thought about a solution using `stopPropagation()` by running through `event.path` array for removing the added class but there are probably another ways to solve the problem.

Here the [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19521/) for option 1 *with `stopPropagation()`*
Here the [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19522/) for option 2 *without `stopPropagation()`*

Answer (score 1):

Register a dragend event on the element that you are dragging. The dragend event is fired when you release the element that is being dragged. The event will be fired regardless of whether it was dropped in a dropzone or not. This way you can separate the drop event from the end of drag. You can filter your process using conditions.